# How to execute functionality on save of a model object on Google AppEngine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, models

On Google AppEngine, we have .put() and put_async(), which are called to save an model object. ().

Being new to GAE, it is not clear to me how I can ensure that some functionality gets executed every time I same an object.

In vanilla Django, I can use signals, or override the .save() method.

How would I achieve similar results on GAE, considering I can actually rely on .put() being called when an object is saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you could accomplish this. You could override the put method with your own code. Just be sure to call the models super put().

However, the route I would choose would be to implement a post put hook (assuming you're using NDB). See the hook method documentation here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass

Comment: I read somewhere else that .put() is not always called, for example, in bulk updates.

As for the second, I am not using ndb, and not sure what it would mean to migrate.

Comment: In regards to the bulk updates and as you are not using ndb check out this blog post from Nick Johnson: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Pre--and-post--put-hooks-for-Datastore-models

Comment: Ok, that looks like a workable solution with the current codebase, thanks for the tip.